# Server-sent events выдает только ошибки

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, sse

Я пытался с помощью SSE сделать обновление данных на странице. Я создал страницу с кодом:

```
<script>
  source = new EventSource("stream/")
  source.onerror=function(e){console.log("ERROR",e)}
  source.onmessage=function(e){console.log("RESULT",e)}
</script>
```

При каждом запросе браузер получает от сервера следующие данные:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2024 05:23:46 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.12.0
Content-Type: text/event-stream
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Connection: close
```

Но в консоль выводятся только ошибки. Как это можно исправить?

[image: Ошибки в консоли]

Comment: Покажите скрипт, который отдает ответ.